# C++ thread request

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++. In my application, there is a method `getOnlineStatus()`:

```
int getOnlineStatus(int num);
```

This method is from third party DLL, it can't be modified.

I call this method to check number status, like this:

```
int num = 123456;
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    num = num + 1;

    int nRet = getOnlineStatus(num);

    if (nRet > 0) {
        cout << num << "status online" << endl;
    }
    else if (nRet == 0) {
        cout << num << "status offline" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << num << "check fail" << endl;
    }

}
```

But every time, it will take 2 seconds to return the `nRet`. So, if I check lots of number, it will take a long time.

Also, I tried to use async, but it's not working, it still takes 2 seconds to return a result one by one.

```
int num = 123456;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        num = num + 1;
        future<int> fuRes = std::async(std::launch::async, getOnlineStatus, num);
        int result = fuRes.get();
        if (result > 0) {
            cout << num << "status online" << endl;
        }
        else if (result == 0) {
            cout << num << "status offline" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << num << "check fail" << endl;
        }

    }
```

Is there any way to open multiple threads to make it show results faster?

Comment: Does it take 2 seconds for each call to `getOnlineStatus` or for all 10000000 of them?

Comment: "*Also, I tried to use async, but it's not working*" - please show what you attempted, maybe you just used it the wrong way. Also, is `getOnlineStatus()` even thread-safe? Do you know if the DLL allows it to be called in parallel to begin with?

Comment: it take 2 seconds for each call to getOnlineStatus

Comment: There is nothing asynchronous in your code: you `get()` after each call, blocking right there until result is available

Comment: Can you provide me the right code

Comment: No one can provide you with the *right code*. We don't know anything about the third-party library you're using or the rest of your code. You've been asked questions about that library that you've failed to answer. Contact the DLL's author to get information about using it with multiple threads.

Comment: call `std::async` twice, getting two different futures. Then call `get` on each future. Did it take 2 seconds, meaning both calls ran in parallel? Or did it take 4 seconds, meaning that you can't speed it up with threads or async?

Comment: future<int> fuRes1 = std::async(std::launch::async, getOnlineStatus, 111111);    
future<int> fuRes2 = std::async(std::launch::async, getOnlineStatus, 222222);
int result1 = fuRes1.get();
int result2 = fuRes2.get();
@Useless  should it like that

Comment: The only place where you can find an authoritative answer to your question is your third party library's documentation. We don't know what it is, how it works, why it is slow, and what can be done about it, sorry.

Comment: @Jason please see my updated answer for  multi-threaded calculations.

Comment: @Jason, as I stated below the Vlad's answer, it is wrong, although very good in the idea, you just need to have more threads to have a kind of a brute-force solution. You will need to balance the number of threads and time of their execution. But the key problem is that your problem definition is not complete. You need to specify why do you need such huge amount of statuses? What is the task and goal? It seems that you misinterpret the task and doing something weird and wasteful. What is the problem to solve on a higher level?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This largely depends on your `third party DLL` - does it even support requests from multiple threads? And if it does - do those requests use shared resources? Like the same internet connection / socket?

If you simplify your question and assume that the `getOnlineStatus()` sleeps for 2 seconds - then yes, you can greatly benefit from issuing multiple requests on different threads and wait in parallel.

Here is how you can simply setup reasonable number of threads to share the workload:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

int status[10'000]{};

int getOnlineStatus(int n) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    return rand();
}

void getStatus(int low, int high) {
    for (int i = low; i < high; i++) {
        status[i] = getOnlineStatus(i);
    }
}

int main()
{
    srand(0);
    const int count = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0, low = 0, high = 10; i < count; ++i, low += 10, high += 10)
        threads.emplace_back(std::thread(getStatus, low, high));
    for (auto& thread : threads)
        thread.join();
    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << count << " threads: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop - start).count() << " ms" << std::endl;

    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10 * count; ++i)
        status[i] = getOnlineStatus(i);
    stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "single thread: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop - start).count() << " ms" << std::endl;
}
```

I get this result:

```
12 threads: 10075 ms
single thread: 120720 ms
```

NOTE: if those worker threads really do nothing, you can run many more of those, reducing total time significantly.

Comment: This is because your code is wrong. It processes only 10*number_of_threads *getOnlineStatuses*. In your case, it is 120 of them. If you correct your code to process all of them, it will take much longer, namely, just 12 times faster than the original code. The problem is that your gathering is semi-sequential, as well.

Comment: @DamirTenishev Not sure I understand your comment; my multi-threaded loop iterates 12 times, processing 10 requests each - the same 120 as a single loop. Single-threaded loop takes almost exactly 12 times longer. Where is the problem? Also, I am not familiar with the `semi-sequential` concept. I do wait for all threads in sequence, but in this case they all take about the same amount of time.

Comment: @Jason has 10000000 statuses to get. Your array has 10000 statuses to store. Meanwhile you acquire and store only 10*12=120 statues, just check in the debugger. Of course, getting 120 statuses with 12 threads are relatively fast, but what for you have is an array for 10000 statuses and Jason still have more. When you code run at least on 10000 statuses it will take 83 times longer than now, making your solution semi-sequentional, which means that although you made it partially parallel, most of it will run sequentially in the loop in getStatus function.

Comment: @DamirTenishev You didn't expect me to wait for 2,000,000 seconds, did you? My code shows that you can scale your execution to number of hardware threads. I also noted that if the worker function REALLY just waits for something, you can run much more threads. That is, of course, if the target DLL supports that.

Comment: That's my point. @Jason is new to C++ and you give him advice with magical numbers 10, 10'000 which make the code a little help for him. As I stated in the comment to him, the code is good idea, but it would require a lot of balancing work in order to help him. You just made it 12 times faster that his, so directly using it would decrease time from 57 days to something less depending on the number of threads computer. And balancing the number of threads is not the task for a newbie. Well, I like your code, I just pointed to the reason why it is fast now. Anyway, it seems that Jason has left )